# Troubleshooting a serial connection

Tags: uart, serial

I have a UART connection from an ESP32 ([esp datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/891/esp32_wroom_32e_esp32_wroom_32ue_datasheet_en-1855879.pdf) to a Quectel BG95 that I cannot get to work.  At first I thought it was code related but after reviewing the AT manual several times. I am thinking it must be circuit related...

Here is a schematic of the connections first we go from the esp through a level shifter [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf) (3.3 to 1.8 V) then to the BG95 [datasheet](https://fccid.io/XMR202005BG95M5/User-Manual/Users-Manual-4826952.pdf).

[image: esp connection]

[image: level shifter]

[image: quectel connection]

Below is the code I used, which sends an AT command with return carriage, according to the manual I should be getting an OK back.

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
int greenpower = 32;
int led = 33;
int pwr = 5;


void setup() {
  
  pinMode(pwr, OUTPUT); //for verifying power to the board
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); //for verifying power to the board
  pinMode(greenpower, OUTPUT); //for allowing power to auxillary processes
  digitalWrite(greenpower, HIGH); //allow power to aux devices
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  //apply power to verification circuit
  digitalWrite(pwr, LOW);  //begin modem start-up
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(pwr, HIGH);  //start-up signal
  delay(750);
  //digitalWrite(pwr, LOW);  //end modem start up sequence
 
  
  delay(5000);  //wait for stabilization

  Serial.begin(115200);  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial2.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1);

}

void loop() {
  Serial2.write("AT\r");
  while (!Serial2.available()) continue;
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    char g = Serial2.read();
    Serial.print(g);
  }
}
```

[image: PCB footprint]

Note that the level shifter is upside down.  But does anyone have a clue as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: From the scope picture of the Rx connected to the Tx indicates a broken or open connection. Since they are connected they should be the same. I use an inexpensive china logic analyzer, it makes this a lot easier to troubleshoot. Then can be gotten to your door for under $10.oo in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are pulling the last hair out.
Assuming everything correct you did, looking at the third scope picture..., very random thoughts:

1. Check if that broken signal pin requires pull-up... Why would it?
2. Ohm (continuity check) that signal pin/trace with adjacent signal traces/pins.
3. Remove and re-solder suspected parts.
4. Ask the assembly house or PCB manufacture to X-ray the assembled board.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions I am updating the question with some recent findings.

Comment: Way to go @Feynman137 !  It looks good,

Comment: Thanks man.. I am confused though I am seeing the signal on the scope but getting blanks in the serial monitor.